# How to control only own animations while still seeing animations of remote players

Tags: animation, multiplayer, synchronization, godot-3

I tried using :

```
if $controller.has_method("is_player"): #Checks if the spawned controller is a player 
    rpc_unreliable("network_update", translation, rotation, $shape_head.rotation) #after hours of tutorials still not clear what it does
```

Now the the player client will only control the animations of its own character and not of every character.

...but!

The player client will not be able to see the animations of other players.

How do I set it up so that the local client sees the animations of other players, while only controlling its own animations?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70427041/6301627